# Query $all with Object Properties

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's say we have these type of documents:

```json
{
    "tags" : [ 
        {
            "fooObject" : {
                "name" : "foo1"
            },
            "fooNumber" : 5,
            "fooOther" : "foo"
        }, 
        {
            "fooObject" : {
                "name" : "foo2"
            },
            "fooNumber" : 4,
            "fooOther" : "moo"
        }, 
        {
            "fooObject" : {
                "name" : "foo3"
            },
            "fooNumber" : 2,
            "fooOther" : "goo"
        }
    ]
}
```

My actual query is:

```
db.foes.find({'tags.fooObject.name': { $all: ['foo1','foo2'] })
```

So I get the documents that contains 'foo1' and 'foo2'.
I would like to extend this query by adding fooNumber. I mean, a match to be made on pairs, on `tags` level. I would pass an array with tags but only specifying `fooObject` and `fooNumber` and get the documents that contains these tags.

If I ask for

```
(foo1,5) and (foo2,4)
```

then this document will match.
If I ask for

```
(foo1,4) and (foo2,4)
```

then it wont match.

Comment: What are you expecting exactly? If I said `"fooNumber": 2` then would you expect this document to match? You do realize that `$all` in this context applies to "all" tags elements and not just a single element when matched with another condition? Or do you basically want to know if the "tags" contains "foo1" 5, and "foo2" 4 for example?

Comment: @NeilLunn Exactly, I want to know if the "tags" contains "foo1" 5, and "foo2" 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean the "combination" of "name" and "value" in the same array element and the whole array contains "both". Therefore you need [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) here with [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/):

```
db.foes.find({
  "$and": [
    { "tags": {
      "$elemMatch": { "fooObject.name": "foo1", "fooNumber": 5 }
    }},
    { "tags": {
      "$elemMatch": { "fooObject.name": "foo2", "fooNumber": 4 }
    }}
  ]
])
```

or you can even write the other way around with [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/)

```
db.foes.find({
  "tags": { "$all": [
    { "$elemMatch": { "fooObject.name": "foo1", "fooNumber": 5 } },
    { "$elemMatch": { "fooObject.name": "foo2", "fooNumber": 4 } }
  ]}
})
```

This would only match documents where "both" conditions were met by array elements within "tags".

The [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator is somewhat a "shortened" form of [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) anyway. And as the operator to use for matching a "pair" of conditions on a singular array element is [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/), then the pairing is only natural.

Comment: The answer solves the question that I asked. But is there any other way? The problem I'm facing now is that I would want to implement this query on Spring Data MongoDB using 'MongoRepository' and this query can't be written to a String query

Comment: @LiLou_ You can always [ask the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). AFAIK at the very least the `$and` expression is supported with spring mongo even if the `$all` version is not. But I would be surprised.